# Disable YouTube custom context menu/ right click menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, contextmenu

When we right click on a YouTube video, it displays this context menu. I need a JavaScript code to disable this context menu when it's right clicked.

[image]

I've found similar question on this topic but that's also unanswered.
[YouTube - don't display context menu on right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664330/youtube-dont-display-context-menu-on-right-click)

Comment: it is about youtube player api or userscript?

Comment: @uingtea I'm looking for userscript.

Answer (score -1):

update:
To detect youtube page change and inject the script

```
document.body.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", function (event) {
  console.log('Youtube page Change')
  $('div video').addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault());
  $('body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<style>.ytp-contextmenu{visibility:hidden;}</style>');
});
```

you can try this

```
// disable HTML5 Video contextmenu
$('div video').addEventListener('contextmenu', e=>e.preventDefault())
// hide element contextmenu by appending custom <style> (CSS)
// cannot use inline CSS
// because the element created after user right click
$('body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<style>.ytp-contextmenu{visibility:hidden;}</style>');
```

`$()` is not jQuery function, change it with `document.querySelector()` if you have trouble

Comment: try paste the code in browser console, it will not working if you navigate from other page, you need to watch for URL or DOMElement change.

Comment: @unigtea I want to execute the code every time a page loads. So I'm using tampermonkey to run this script. This script works in browser console but doesn't works in tampermonkey. How to make this work?